# C++ Compiler Error C2362

Tags: c++

The code is like this

```
{
   int a;

     if( a == 0 )
     {
          std::string  str("some");
          goto CLEANUP;
     }


return;
CLEANUP: 
     printf("CLEANUP");


}
```

this is giving me error Compiler Error C2362
initialization of 'identifier' is skipped by 'goto label'

I moved *std::string  str("some");* after *int a;* still it is giving me same error

Comment: goto is bad style i know, but its already written by previous programmers.

Comment: It looks like some of the code at the end is messed up?

Comment: Post the **actual** code

Answer (score 4):

Is it that your:

```
goto CLEANUP:
```

Is supposed to be:

```
goto CLEANUP;
```

(semicolon not colon)

Answer (score 4):

Compiler Error C2362

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6s80d9f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
 if( a == 0 )
     {
          std::string  str("some");
          goto CLEANUP:
     }
```

should be

```
goto CLEANUP;
```

Comment: please forget syntax errors. i request you to tell abt concept error.

Answer (score 3):

```
goto CLEANUP:
```

should be,

```
goto CLEANUP;
```

[Also, make sure your code compiles as `printf` is not proper at the end]